# Generate dynamic number of plots based on factor levels of user input file

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, shiny, reactive

In a shiny app I would like to create separate plots for each factor level in a file that a user inputs. This factor may have anywhere from 2 to 10+ levels. In the toy example this factor is `plotGroup`. I would like it to output as in the toy example below but have separate plots rather than facet. I have used this script as a guide but I am not able to figure out how to fit the reactive getData() function within this framework.
https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415/

Data

```
structure(list(plotGroup = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "C", "C", "C", "C"), xGroup = c("D", "D", "E", "E", "D", 
"D", "E", "E", "D", "D", "E", "E"), yVar = c(5L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 
3L, 4L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Example app giving desired output using facets

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  headerPanel("Dynamic number of plots"),
  
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("fileIn", 
              "Load input file",
              multiple = F)
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  getData <- reactive({
    req(input$fileIn)
    dataIn <- as.data.frame(fread(input$fileIn$datapath))
    return(dataIn)
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    getData() %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = xGroup, y = yVar)) +
      facet_wrap(~plotGroup) + geom_point()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Example of trying using the gist link above. This gives an `Operation not allowed without an active reactive context` error.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  headerPanel("Dynamic number of plots"),
  
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("fileIn", 
              "Load input file",
              multiple = F)
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("plot1")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  getData <- reactive({
    req(input$fileIn)
    dataIn <- as.data.frame(fread(input$fileIn$datapath))
    return(dataIn)
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderUI({
    plotOutputList <- lapply(levels(getData()$plotGroup),
                             function(i){
                               plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep = "_")
                               plotOutput(plotname)
                             })
    do.call(tagList, plotOutputList)
  })
  
  for(i in levels(getData()$plotGroup)){
    local({
      iCurrent <- i
      plotname <- paste("plot", iCurrent, sep = "_")
      
      output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
        getData() %>%
          filter(plotGroup == iCurrent) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = xGroup, y = yVar)) +
          geom_point()
      })
    })
  }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The main point of that gist is that they are using  a `uiOutput` rather than `plotOutput`. This allows them to add multiple `plotOutput` to the `uiOutput` at runtime because you can have only one plot per `plotOutput`

Comment: That makes sense, I added the example of what I tried using `uiOutput` which then gives me a `active reactive context` error. I have a feeling I may need to add a reactive statement somewhere around where `getData()` is called but I'm stuck on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, the data you shared shows that `plotGroup` is a character value, not a factor. This means that `levels()` will return NULL since it doesn't have any. Rather than `levels()`, you can use `unique()` to get the different values in that column.

The second problem is that your `for` loop needs to be in a reactive context. The easiest fix is just to wrap it in an `observe` block.

The server function should look like this

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  getData <- reactive({
    return(data)
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderUI({
    plotOutputList <- lapply(unique(getData()$plotGroup),
                             function(i){
                               plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep = "_")
                               plotOutput(plotname)
                             })
    do.call(tagList, plotOutputList)
  })
  
  observe({
    for(i in unique(getData()$plotGroup)){
    local({
      iCurrent <- i
      plotname <- paste("plot", iCurrent, sep = "_")
      
      output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
        getData() %>%
          filter(plotGroup == iCurrent) %>%
          ggplot(aes(x = xGroup, y = yVar)) +
          geom_point()
      })
    })
  }})
}
```

Comment: Brilliant that works in the toy example and in my large dataset, thanks so much